# Change the default file download path for Edge using selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I was using selenium-ruby for automating browser application.
I want to simulate file download scenario. 
When I want to execute for chrome I had a method named "download_path", its value can be changed at run-time and when download file it will be saved at my destination path.

But, when I execute the same code for edge there is no method support for "download_path" in edge.

Is there any way to set my default download location at runtime?

**Chrome Code:**

```
@browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

# code for navigating to downloads page and clicking on download button

@browser.download_path = File.dirname(filePath)
@browser.close
```

**Edge Code:**

```
@browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :edge

# code for navigating to downloads page and clicking on download button


@browser.download_path = File.dirname(filePath)
@browser.close
```

**Error**

```
Error: test_01_click_download_pass(Download_A_File): NoMethodError: undefined method `download_path=' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::EdgeHtml::Driver:0x0000000004cdd8a0>
```

**Environment Details:**

```
OS: Windows 10
Programming Language: ruby (v2.5.5)
Gem : selenium-webdriver (v alpha4)
```

Comment: Hi, Is it working for other browsers?

Comment: @Rajagopalan - I use to automate for Edge, IE, Chrome. No, it is not working for Edge & IE. I think chrome alone has the feature to change the download path at runtime through the method "download_path"

Comment: @Rajagopalan - I have raised feature implementation request #7964 in selenium forum. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the [selenium EdgeDriver library](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/edge/EdgeDriver.html) and the [Microsoft Edge WebDriver document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver), it seems that there is no way to set the change the download file path via the selenium Edge webdriver.

I suggest you could directly change the default download location in Edge via the Edge settings. Besides, you could also try to change the Edge browser setting through change the Registry. More detail information, please check the following link:

[Change default download location in Edge](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/edge_other-edge_win10/change-default-download-location-in-edge/74677e11-1f32-41ec-b825-da0ac0a52215)