# Loading Edge 83 with Selenium, in EdgeHTML mode (UseChromium = false). Returns Error

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to launch Edge using the EdgeHTML renderer mode, within Selenium, using Visual Studio C#.. I'm using the version 83.0.478.58 (64bit) and the driver 83.0.478.58 (64bit). Installed via nuget.

If I launch the browser using it works fine...

```
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.UseChromium = true;
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"C:\temp\"); 
EdgeDriver edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

By default UseChromium is False, which should launch the browser in the EdgeHTML renderer. If I use the below code it will error out.

```
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"C:\temp\"); 
EdgeDriver edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

The browser will open a new instance, but once the browser is open. The code bugs out and returns the error message,

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The new session command returned a value ('Unknown error') that is not a valid JSON object.'

If I just try and simply initialise without the options, I still get the same error.

Anyone got any ideas? Looking around I see documentation and guides all over that launch the browser without UseChromium.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to set the default download directory for the **MS Edge legacy (EdgeHTML) browser** using the Selenium code.

I want to inform you that it is possible to set the default download directory for the **MS Edge (Chromium) browser** as you had already tried that successfully but it is not possible to set the default download directory for the **MS Edge legacy (EdgeHTML) browser** using the Selenium code.

As a workaround, you can try to set the download directory manually.

References:

1. [Change the default file download path for Edge using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59934307/change-the-default-file-download-path-for-edge-using-selenium)
2. [Change default download location in Edge](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/edge_other-edge_win10/change-default-download-location-in-edge/74677e11-1f32-41ec-b825-da0ac0a52215?auth=1)

Comment: Thank you, thats useful to know. Unfortunately commenting out the download option and trying to launch the browser with options.UseChromium = false; still doens't work and resulting in same not valid JSON error. Am I right in assumign that UseChromium false should launch the Chromium install of Edge in EdgeHTML renderer?

Comment: Did you download the Edge legacy web driver? You cannot automate the MS Edge legacy web driver with the Edge Chromium web driver. You can visit this link and download the correct version of the web driver for Edge legacy browser then after again try to automate it. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ Let me know if you have further questions or want the detailed steps for automating the MS Edge legacy browser. I will try to provide suggestions for it.